# How to take data from URL

Tags: php, url

I am developing API for my company. Normally, we use POST & GET method to send form data to other website or another page. But what I want, If we want to send data in URL like
      `http://www.example.com/data1/data2/data3`

like that.
In that case, Data1, Data2, Data3 is our data and I want this data in PHP.
I am searching on that but I can't find what I want.

Comment: You need to add the rewrite mode in your htaccess file

Comment: are you asking how to parse the URL in PHP? - otherwise everyone below might be in the right track...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Apache mod_rewrite (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

You can rewrite `data1/data2/data3` into `?thing1=data1&thing2=data2&thing3=data3`, then use `$_GET` like you usually would...

Comment: That's webserver specific though.

Comment: Now I am accessing data with GET Method but don't want to use GET method.

Comment: OP, it seems like you want to access the data from within PHP, but you want to make the URLs look pretty, right? That's what `mod_rewrite` is for. It takes your pretty URLs and converts them to a query string so PHP can parse the data... Gill, you are right, but short of having a folder structure that accounts for every possible combination of data that could be submitted (including incorrect data?) with a PHP script at the bottom of each node, I don't know how you do it without `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called **URL Rewriting** which is supported by all major Web Servers like Apache and NGINX.

To read more about URL rewriting in apache go thorugh:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

To read more about neat urls in NGINX go through https://serverfault.com/questions/653177/clean-url-with-several-params-in-nginx

In apache servers clean URLS can be achieved by enabling a module called `mod_rewrite` and a simple way to do it is using the .htaccess file.

In nginx you can use web.config file.

After having clean URL's you can use any method from GET,PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE etc. but remember if the user enters your URL in your browser then it is always a GET request by default.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by simply fetching the entire URL and `preg_split()` the string as below code

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // this gives you /folder1/folder2/THIS_ONE/file.php
$folders = preg_split('/', $path); // splits folders in array
$what_we_need = $folders[3];
```

Comment: This requires having a folder structure that accounts for every possible combination of data that could be submitted (including incorrect data?) with a PHP script at the bottom of each node. Is that what OP wants?